# Flutter: add string to List with .addAll()

Tags: flutter, dart

I have to add value that I receive from the api server.

```
print(userInfo['ID']['List'][0].runtimeType); // returns String
(userInfo['ID']['List'] as List).addAll(result['id_num']);
```

However, I am receiving `I/flutter (23015): type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'`

How can I add value to the `List` in this case? `Result['id_num']` also returns the type of `String`.

Comment: use add instead of addAll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using `addAll`:**

`addAll` accepts an `Iterable` but you're giving it a `String`. All you need to do is create an `Iterable` from the `String` like this:

```
(userInfo['ID']['List'] as List).addAll([result['id_num']]);
```

---

**Using `add`:**

If you don't wish to use `addAll`, you can directly add `String` using `add` method:

```dart
(userInfo['ID']['List'] as List).add(result['id_num']);
```